# Do Segment Registers change at runtime?

Tags: assembly

Can the Segment Registers change during execution of a program? I am sure it is possible to change them in assembly, but if I write in c or c++ and compile, and have a few inline `asm` instructions, can I count on the `SS` register and other segment registers to stay unchanged?

Comment: This is a way too general question. It depends on particular OS and particular C compiler. In most cases, xS stays unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are under a typical 32 or 64 bit operating system then you can pretty much ignore segment registers (except when dealing with thread-local storage, exception handling or system stuff). `CS`, `DS`, `ES` and `SS` all address the same memory and they don't change. Compilers assume this as well.